# Socket 775 or 1156?

Tags: motherboard, cpu

I currently have Pentium 4 and biostar motherboard with LGA 478 socket.
I want to upgrade so that I am safe for another 7-8 years.

Should I upgrade to LGA775 ans hence Core 2 series or LGA1156 and Core ix series?

Update:

Lets assume I go with LGA1156. So, what processors (Intel/AMD) are compatible? And, roughly, will LGA1156 be mainstream for atleast 5-6 years? 
So that, if need be, I can upgrade only processor in the future?

My usage is quite varied - father uses it for accounting purpose which requires normal CPU power, I use it for games and software development purposes which require faster CPU.

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: In the next 5-6 years Socket <insert-name/number-here> would have replaced LGA1156/1366

Comment: oh. then what is the best motherboard-processor option for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be wise for you to save on getting what is now obsolete technology.  If you are going to keep the new computer for as long as 7-8 years, certainly do not get a S775 system.

Comment: so according to you i should go with 1156 or better 1366? and is core ix series supported on 1156?

Comment: S1366 systems are expensive, so it depends on your budget. As you do not seem to upgrade very often, you probably would be wasting money on bleeding edge power, but you should still get something up-to-date if you are going to keep it for a long time. I'd suggest you look at getting a 'Lynnfield' S1156 Core i5-7xx or S1156 Core i7-8xx system (which adds Hyper-Threading).

Comment: Ok. S1156/LGA1156 difference? And are AMD processors supported on the same sockets?

Comment: Sorry, S1156 and LGA1156 are the same thing.  Bear in mind that Core i7 is available on both LGA1156 and LGA1366 and both i5 and i7 are available on LGA1156 (the latter just adds Hyper-Threading).  It's all quite confusing, so Wikipedia can help you out.  AMD sockets are totally different.

Comment: That's probably a good idea, as you can always upgrade to a LGA1156 Core i5 or i7 at a later date. It's a much better idea than getting a Core 2 system.

Answer (score 0):

> Core 2 processor on LGA1366 (I guess that is supported?)

Core 2 series is obsolete, is not supported LGA 1366/LGA 1156 series.

> Should I upgrade to LGA775 ans hence Core 2 series or LGA1156 and Core ix series?

Without knowing your usage - it's impossible to say. For regular office correspondence & browsing, the LGA1156 series of processors will serve you fine. You can also have a look at AMD's series of processors - but like I said, without more details it's not possible to say

Comment: updated the question.